# Using absolute/relative position in email template

Tags: css, html, email, html-email

I am trying to apply absolute/relative position to an image inside an email. There's an image inside a span which needs absolute positioning to preserve line height of the paragraph.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to accomplish. [image]

I got to know absolute and relative positioning can't be used inside email templates, is it possible to fix the image positioning without using absolute positioning.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you're currently trying? I'm not sure why you can't use Margins, tables or borders to move the image.

Answer (score 4):

The [`position` CSS property has very poor support in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/), even the ones considered to have decent CSS support.

You're best bet is to try negating the image's `line-height`, something like this:

```
<p style="margin: 0 0 10px; line-height: 130%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam dictum varius. Integer mollis, elit nec commodo elementum, justo nunc faucibus lectus. <img src="" style="display: inline; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 0;">
```

Line heights vary depending on the font and email clients tends to treat `line-height` a little differently. This isn't perfect, but it'll get you closer to your screenshot above.

Answer (score 2):

This actually has a code entity:

```
 U+026A0 UNICODE
 &#x26A0; HEX CODE
 &#9888; HTML CODE
```

which you could then just style inline with more code:

```
 <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sic met <strong style="color: #fff126">&#x26A0;</strong></p>
```

Snippet:

```html
 <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sic met <strong style="color: #fff126; back">&#9888;</strong></p>
```

The thing with using `position: absolute` in html emails is that they will 100% break on Outlook.

Comment: May not look like much but if you use the `&#x26A0;` on people's phones they will see the correct warning emoji